# How to select multiple rows in a JTable for drag and drop?

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable in which the table is allowing me to select and drag only one row at a time initially, and then it allows me multiple row select and drag from the second time, how do i make it allow me to select multiple rows for the first time also.

```
     private void initialize()
     {
        propertyTable = GUI.getTable();
        Vector columnVector = new Vector();
        columnVector.addElement("Property Name");
        columnVector.addElement("Alias Name");
        propertyTableModel = new PropertyTableModel(getEmptyDataVector(),columnVector);

        propertyTable.setModel(propertyTableModel);
        propertyTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);

        propertyTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        propertyTable.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(47,81,121));
        propertyTable.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);

        propertyTable.setDragEnabled(true);
        propertyTable.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler());


        propertyColumn = propertyTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        aliasColumn = propertyTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        propertyColumn.setCellRenderer(new PropertyAliasColumnTableCellRenderer());
        aliasColumn.setCellRenderer(new PropertyAliasColumnTableCellRenderer());

        tablePanel = createPropertyNamesTablePanel();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        add(tablePanel ,"Center");
    }


   private Vector getEmptyDataVector()
   {
       Vector dataVector = new Vector();
       Vector rowVector = new Vector();
       rowVector.addElement("");
       rowVector.addElement("");
       dataVector.addElement(rowVector);
       return dataVector;
   }
```

Comment: How does your code look? What have you tried?

Comment: Adding a sample/executable code segment will make it easier to provide a solution.

Comment: yes, i have added the code